# Visibility in Java's finalize

Tags: java, android

Given implementation below

```
class Foo {
    private RuntimeException closed = new IllegalStateException("not closed");

    public void close() {
        closed = null;
    }

    protected void finalize() {
        if (closed != null)
            closed.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Does `closed` need to be defined `volatile`? Does behaviour change if `Foo` is instantiated on stack?

I tried to go after [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.2), [JSR-133](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) and [The JSR-133 Cookbook for Compiler Writers](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) but couldn't really digest specification's text neither could find a definitive article around the question.

In addition this is what 'JSR-133 Cookbook for Compiler Writers' says:

> Finalization support may require barriers (*within garbage collectors*)
>   to ensure that Object.finalize code sees all stores to all fields
>   prior to the objects becoming unreferenced. This is usually ensured
>   via the synchronization used to add and remove references in reference
>   queues.

Answer (score 1):

*Foo is instantiated on stack*, this is an object, it will be on the heap, the reference will be on the stack.

And you do realise that finalize *might not be called at all*?

Comment: so how would you word "void foo() {Foo f = new Foo();}" ?

Comment: *f* - the reference will be on the stack, the Foo object it references will be on the heap. Once the method ends, the reference will be cleared from the stack, the object *will be eligible for garbage collection*, but will be cleared when GC actually runs.

Comment: so escape analysis and possible stack allocation is just a hype?

Comment: @auselen variables are still allocated on the stack. In java 8 (have to find the reference) objects *might* be allocated on the stack, but even like this, you have to think about them as on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

According to [JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> *"There is a happens-before edge from the end of a constructor of an object to the start of a finalizer (§12.6) for that object."*.

However, if `close()` is called after object construction, there will be a write to the `closed` field in between.  In order for the finalizer thread to be be guaranteed to see the updated value, either `closed` must be volatile or it must be accessed and updated under a mutex (or equivalent) ... in order to add the necessary "happens-before".

Comment: am I interpreting jsr-133 cookbook article in correctly? It says "finalize code sees all stores..."

Comment: @auselen - No it doesn't say that. It says that a memory barrier *may* be required to ensure that the finalize code sees all stores. It does not guarantee that that memory barrier will be there ... and the JLS doesn't strictly require it to be there either.  My interpretation is that this is **advice** to compiler writers.

Comment: It says "Finalization support may require barriers *(within garbage collectors)* to ensure that Object.finalize code sees all stores to all fields prior to the objects becoming unreferenced."

Comment: @auselen - OK, but it certainly does not say what you claimed it said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `closed` needs to be declared as `volatile` to ensure value changes visibility. Also please be advised that there is no guarantees that `finalize()` will ever be called so relying on its call is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If a field can be changed after initialization access to it should be synchronized for the class to be thread-safe. Since finalize() will be called from a different thread than close() method it may see outdated close value

Comment: So as a rule, since finalize would run on a different 'finalizer' thread, anything you would access in finalize should be volatile? Can we find some spec around this?

Comment: it's a general rule, fixed answer

Comment: while I think this should be the way I'm looking for a reference to that general rule.

Comment: If you check  jsr-133-cookbook link it says "Finalization support may require barriers (within garbage collectors) to ensure that Object.finalize code sees all stores to all fields prior to the objects becoming unreferenced. This is usually ensured via the synchronization used to add and remove references in reference queues." which would conflict with what we claim.